# diffuse shading and ambiant shading

Tags: java, graphics

I have some questions about computer graphics:

- How can I compute diffuse shading with multiple light in java ?
- How can I compute ambiant shading with multiple light in java ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Independently of how many lights there are, the lighting is computed as follows:

```
ambient = material.ambient * light.ambient
diffuse = material.diffuse * light.diffuse * dot(normal, direction_to_light)
```

The direction and normal vectors must be normalized. Furthermore, if the `dot()` is less than zero, the resulting diffuse color is just black.

If you have multiple lights, each light is added to the result. So e.g.

```
result = ambient_light1 + diffuse_light1 + ambient_light2 + diffuse_light2 ...
```

Comment: Should diffuse be computed for each colour ( R, G, B ), separetely ? In other words, Will I use this formula for each of them ?

Comment: Yes, each channel is calculated separately.